# Is it possible to run as root which have logged in user id using getuid()?

Tags: macos, cocoa, terminal, root

I am developing a mac Cocoa app which needs to run second application.
The following is the relevant form of the second application which i need to run

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    uid_t           gRealUserID =  getuid();
    printf("User id:%d\n",gRealUserID);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the second terminal app should run root and also 'getuid()'  get current logged in user.My first app is running with root privilege.

so in short if I build the above code to executable named "test"
and run in terminal

```
$ ./test
User id:501
```

if we run

```
$ sudo ./test
User id:0
```

I want to know is there any possible way by which if I do command like

```
$ sudo ./test
```

prints

```
User id:501
```

**Interesting observation:** If I authorize root privilege from a non root application using `SFAuthorization` it works as expected..But unfortunately I can't do that now, do to some client requirement changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` runs a program as if it was launched by root, hence `getuid` returns 0. What I think you are looking for is a *set user ID* program - this is a file mode setting which sets the *effective UID* of a program to that of the executable file's owner, so an executable owned by root is executed with an effective ID of root but a *real ID* of the user launching the program.

See the manual entries for `chmod(2)`, `geteuid(2)`, `getuid(2)` etc. for details.

HTH

Comment: thanks @CRD I will try.. but why when using SFAuthorization autharization works?

Comment: The authorisation works in both cases, it is just how the real and effective IDs are setup. If you read up of these you will discover how a set UID program can produce the setup `sudo` does - indeed do an `ls -l /usr/bin/sudo` and you will see it is a set UID program.